# Trouble with Carrierware and nested_forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, nested-forms

I'm trying to implement Carrierware and nested_form in order to get multiple uploads for my model, but am running into trouble.

My model:

```
class Idea < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :suggested_files_by_owner_attributes 
    has_many :suggested_files_by_owner, :class_name => 'Attachment', :as => :attachable
    has_many :suggested_files, :class_name => 'Attachment', :as => :attachable
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :suggested_files_by_owner
end
```

My model:

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :file
  # belongs_to :comment
  belongs_to :attachable, :polymorphic => true
  mount_uploader :file, FileUploader
end
```

My Schema (I migrated):

```
create_table "attachments", :force => true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at",      :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      :null => false
    t.string   "title"
    t.integer  "attachable_id"
    t.string   "attachable_type"
```

I migrated:

```
class AddFileToIdeas < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :ideas, :file, :string
  end
end
```

My View:

```
= nested_form_for @idea, :url => {:action => "update", :controller=>"ideas"}, :html=>{:multipart => true} do |f|
    =f.text_field :title, value: @idea.title
    = f.text_area :description, :size => '30x7', :id => 'description'
    %br 

    = f.label :privacy, "Make Private" 
    = f.check_box :is_private
    %p
    = f.fields_for :suggested_files_by_owner do |a_form|
        = a_form.file_field :file
        = a_form.link_to_remove "Remove"
    = f.link_to_add "Add Attachment", :suggested_files_by_owner


    = f.submit 'Save and Post'
```

My error occurs when I hit submit:

```
undefined method `file_will_change!'
```

Also, on the view, when I click "Add Attachment", two uploader boxes show up instead of one.
Can anyone help me figure out my issue(s)?

UPDATE
My old error:

```
uninitialized constant Idea::SuggestedFilesByOwner
```

I needed to add `:class_name => 'Attachment'` into the association line.  See above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`undefined method 'file_will_change!'` occurs if you forget to add a column in your model's db table. You have to add `file` column to `Attachment`, not to `Idea`, because this column must be added to the model which has the uploader:

```
rails g migration AddFileToAttachments file:string
rake db:migrate
```